# Help with ifstream in programming test

Tags: c++

I recently did a programming test in which there was a ifstream section which I could not solve.  Since then I have been trying to solve the problem in my free time to no avail.

The problem is basically to read from a binary file and extract the information there.

Here is the file format:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| File Offset (in Bytes)| Value Type                 | Value Description     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0                     | Unsigned Integer (32 bits) | number of entities    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4                     | Entity information (see    | Entity 0              |
|                       | below)                     |                       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4+32                  | Entity Information         | Entity 1              |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ...                   | ...                        | ...                   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4 + (32 * N)          | Entity Information         | Entity N              |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Entity Information:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Offsett (in Bytes)| Value Type                 | Value Description         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0                 | Unsigned short (16 bits)   | Unique ID                 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2                 | Unsigned short (16 bits)   | Entity type ID            |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4                 | Single-precision float (32 | Position X coordinate     |
|                   | bits)                      |                           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 8                 | Single-precision float (32 | Position Y coordinate     |
|                   | bits)                      |                           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 12                | Single-precision float (32 | Forward Normal X          |
|                   | bits)                      | Component                 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 16                | Single-precision float (32 | Forward Normal Y          |
|                   | bits)                      | Component                 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here is my code:

```
void readFile() 
{
  ifstream ifs ( "binaryFile.bin" , ifstream::in );

  while (ifs.good())
  {
    int numEntities = 0;
    ifs.read( (char*)&(numEntities), sizeof(unsigned short));

    for(int i=0; i<numEntities; i++)
    {
      unsigned short uID;
      unsigned short eID;
      float x;
      float y;
      float forward_x;
      float forward_y;

      ifs.read( (char*)&(uID), sizeof(unsigned short) );
      ifs.read( (char*)&(eID), sizeof(unsigned short) );
      ifs.read( (char*)&(x), sizeof(float) );
      ifs.read( (char*)&(y), sizeof(float) );
      ifs.read( (char*)&(forward_x), sizeof(float) );
      ifs.read( (char*)&(forward_y), sizeof(float) );
    }
  }
  ifs.close();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not make `numEntities` an `unsigned short`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you are having problems, what output are you seeing, and how is it different from what you expect to see?

Some general advice: For one thing, if you are going to be reading in binary data, try [open](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/open/)ing the stream in binary mode.

Also, your first `read` operation stores data into an `int`, but the length read was `unsigned short`.  Was this intentional?

When you cast your pointer to `char*` for the first parameter to `read`, try using an explicit `reinterpret_cast<char *>` instead.

Comment: I just facepalmed so hard that the neighbors heard it.  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to make sure that you are reading the proper number of bytes for each item, use the slightly less error-prone syntax `sizeof(numEntities)` instead of `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're treating `numEntities` like a 16bit short when (according to the specs and your declaration) it's supposed to be a 32bit integer.  You're reading two bytes (`sizeof(unsigned short)`) instead of 4; try `sizeof(int)`, and throw some of these in there:

```
assert(sizeof(unsigned short) == 2);
assert(sizeof(int) == 4);
assert(sizeof(float) == 4);
```